# ASP.Net - Sort Textbox Values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a multiline textbox with some text in it. I want to sort this text now but my problem is, that ASP.net doesn't know the "Lines" (not a Member...)

To sort values in a textbox I found this code and understood it. In Visual Basic it works but not for ASP.net...

```
Private Function SortData(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal size As Int32) As String()
    ' The array that contains the initial set of items (not sorted)
    ' The size is decresed by 1 unit because the array starts indexing from 0
    Dim items(size - 1) As String
    ' Verify that the specified size is exactly the number of lines
    ' to be sorted in the TextBox control.
    If size <> TextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    Else
        For i = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            items(i) = TextBox1.Lines(i)
        Next

        Array.Sort(items)
    End If
    Return items
End Function
```

Is it possible to sort text in a Textbox with ASP.Net?

The text in the textbox looks like:
Molly
Rick
Anderson
Stevson

output should be:
Anderson
Molly
Rick
Stevson
(sorted by A-Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the string should be split at occurrence of some Char or group of Char, like space, vbCr, vbLf or vbCrLf, you may use [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If your split demands a smarter pattern recognition, you could try [`Regex.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).